# How to click a button in protractor that only becomes visible on hover

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, jasmine, protractor

I am trying to click a button on my application that only becomes visible when you hover over the area of the button. I am wondering if there is a way to click on the button before it becomes visible or to hover and then click.

I have already tried to use a regular click() with a browser.wait, but since the button isn't visible or clickable until a hover is performed, it hasn't worked.

```
 //Delete Created Topic Clean Up
         myData.click(); //goes to topic home page
         browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.urlContains('home'), 5000); //waits until url is on home page
  browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(deleteLastTopic), 5000); //waits for delete button to be clickable
        // deleteLastTopic.click(); //clicks delete button
         browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(deleteConfirm), 5000); //wait for delete prompt to be clickable
         deleteConfirm.click(); //clicks delete confirm
```

With the above code, I have no problem clicking the confirm delete, but the initial delete button only appears on hover, so it will always timeout on the wait for deleteLastTopic to be clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this approach, that I use:
`deleteLastTopic.browser_.actions().mouseMove(deleteLastTopic).click().perform();`